# How to display "Loading.." while switching tabs

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm interested is it possible to create tabs with Primefaces using this [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf)?
The idea is to create dynamically loaded tabs and when I switch between pages to display "Loading" at the top right of the page. What are the usual ways is this case?

Answer (score 1):

The example you reference in your question carries the answer to the question. Generally, you have two options

1. Primefaces [`ajaxStatus`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf) component is designed specifically for your use case and is also the same component used in the dynamic tab sample you linked (albeit the PF team neglected to reference/declare it in the sample markup for that example). It's the same component that is used to generate the "loading" pinwheel you see in that example
2. A more powerful/exotic option is the [`blockUi`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/blockUI.jsf) component that will achieve the same effect, albeit with a little more in terms of options and visual effect.